# Call function via for loop with functons as a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to write a PyQt5 application. All the list items in list variables are LineEdit objects of a form. On calling a reset function, I wish to set them to specific values for which I am trying to write a for loop instead of hard coding.

However, I cant use the list items in variables as objects as they are object attributes in other file and doing

```
self.eval(variables[i]).setText(default_0_values[i])
```

**does't work**, since eval is not an attribute of self.
However, if I run

```
self.nGASLineEdit.setText(2)
```

**it works**. But I **cant seem to be able to automate** it  and I'm stuck. Need a work around this.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets,uic

variables=[
'nGASLineEdit','nDELTALineEdit','iMIPLineEdit','nDVECLineEdit','nSEEDLineEdit','eSTARTLineEdit','eTHRMLineEdit','eCUTLineEdit','nGAS1LineEdit','nGAS2LineEdit','nGAS3LineEdit','nGAS4LineEdit','nGAS5LineEdit','nGAS6LineEdit','fRAC1LineEdit','fRAC2LineEdit','fRAC3LineEdit','fRAC4LineEdit','fRAC5LineEdit','fRAC6LineEdit','tEMPLineEdit','tORRLineEdit','eFIELDLineEdit','bMAGLineEdit','bTHETALineEdit','iWRITELineEdit','iPENLineEdit','dETEFFLineEdit','eXCWGHTLineEdit','kGASLineEdit','lGASLineEdit','lCMPLineEdit','lRAYLineEdit','lPAPLineEdit','lBRMLineEdit','iECASCLineEdit'
]

default_0_values=[
2,100,5,1,0,1.0,1.5,2.0,
2 ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
]

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('main.ui',self)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.reset())

    def select_func(self,func_name):
        return func_name

    def reset(self):
        global variables
        global default_0_values
        for i in range(len(variables)):
            self.eval(variables[i]).setText(default_0_values[i])




if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[UI file in .ui format](https://gist.github.com/fireballpoint1/d5dfbe8311920ae3dcf65df8f71731d3)

[UI file in .py format](https://gist.github.com/fireballpoint1/537bb2ae878277751a37efc35b44c597)

Comment: please, show your .ui

Comment: @eyllanesc updated as links in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `eval` is a bad programming practice and in this case it is unnecessary, in addition to putting `self.eval(...)` these are indicating that eval is a function of the Window class and clearly it is not.. On the other hand if you only read variables it is not necessary to use `global`. Instead we can use `getattr()` as shown below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets,uic

variables=['nGASLineEdit','nDELTALineEdit','iMIPLineEdit','nDVECLineEdit','nSEEDLineEdit','eSTARTLineEdit','eTHRMLineEdit','eCUTLineEdit','nGAS1LineEdit','nGAS2LineEdit','nGAS3LineEdit','nGAS4LineEdit','nGAS5LineEdit','nGAS6LineEdit','fRAC1LineEdit','fRAC2LineEdit','fRAC3LineEdit','fRAC4LineEdit','fRAC5LineEdit','fRAC6LineEdit','tEMPLineEdit','tORRLineEdit','eFIELDLineEdit','bMAGLineEdit','bTHETALineEdit','iWRITELineEdit','iPENLineEdit','dETEFFLineEdit','eXCWGHTLineEdit','kGASLineEdit','lGASLineEdit','lCMPLineEdit','lRAYLineEdit','lPAPLineEdit','lBRMLineEdit','iECASCLineEdit']

default_0_values=[2,100,5,1,0,1.0,1.5,2.0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('main.ui',self)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.reset)

    def reset(self):
        for le, val in zip(variables, default_0_values):
            getattr(self, le).setText(str(val))

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: worked like a charm. what exactly does getattr return ?

Comment: @fireball.1 see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr